# Web Api 2 Json Formatter

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api2

Using Web Api 2, I have my JSON formatting setup correctly as far as I know and when returning a simple model, the data is formatted in camel case.

```
HttpConfiguration globalConfig = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
globalConfig.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
globalConfig.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
```

For example a Model with property **UserName** is returned as **userName** to the client.
The issue is that when I return an IEnumerable, the properties are not in camel case.

In all cases I return a IHttpActionResult with return `this.Ok(result);`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this post](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/76057-return-camelcase-property-names-from-api-controller), Whenever using IEnumerable with json response,

```
// camelcase properties when it is json response
var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Refer to the link for more details :)